# Django create subquery with values for last n days

Tags: python, django, postgresql, django-models, django-orm

I am using Django 3.1 with Postgres, and this is my abridged model:

```py
class PlayerSeasonReport:
    player = models.ForeignKey(Player)
    competition_season = models.ForeignKey(CompetitionSeason)

class PlayerPrice:
    player_season_report = models.ForeignKey(PlayerSeasonReport)
    price = models.IntegerField()
    date = models.DateTimeField()
    # unique on (price, date)
```

I'm querying on the PlayerSeasonReport to get aggregate information about all players, in particular I would like the prices for the last n records (so the last price, the 7th-to-last price, etc.)

I currently get the PlayerSeasonReport queryset and annotate it like this:

```py
base_query = PlayerSeasonReport.objects.filter(competition_season_id=id)

# This works fine
last_value = base_query.filter(
    pk=OuterRef('pk'),
).order_by(
   'pk',
   '-player_prices__date'
).distinct('pk').annotate(
   value=F('player_prices__price')
)

# Pull the value from a week ago
# This produces a value but is logically incorrect
# I am interested in the 7th-to-last value, not really from a week ago from day of query
week_ago = datetime.datetime.now() - datetime.timedelta(7)
value_7d_ago = base_query.filter(
    pk=OuterRef('pk'),
    player_prices__date__gte=week_ago,
    ).order_by(
       'pk',
       'fantasy_player_prices__date'
    ).distinct('pk').annotate(
        value=F('player_prices__price')
    )


return base_query.annotate(
    value=Subquery(
         value.values('value'),
         output_field=FloatField()
      ),
    # Same for value_7d_ago
    # ...
    # Many other annotations
)
```

Getting the most recent value works fine, but getting the last n values doesn't. **I shouldn't be using datetime concepts in my logic, since what I'm really interested in is in the n-to-last values.**

I've tried annotating the max date, then filtering based on this annotation, and also somehow slicing the subquery, but I can't seem to get any of it right.

It's worth noting that a price may not exist (there may be no record for n values in the past), in which case it should be null (the annotation based on datetime works)

How can I annotate the price values for the last n days?

Answer (score 0):

Sorted:

```py
base_query = PlayerSeasonReport.objects.filter(id=id)

# ...other manipulations on base query

prices = PlayerPrice.objects.filter(
    fantasy_player_season_report=OuterRef('pk')
).order_by('-date')


return base_query.annotate(
    price=Subquery(
        prices.values('price')[:1],
        output_field=FloatField()
    ),
    prev_day_price=Subquery(
        prices.values('price')[1:2],
        output_field=FloatField()
    ),
    # ...
)
```

Explanation:

We query on the child model (PlayerPrice) and join on the pk of the PlayerSeasonReport.

`prices.values('price')[i:j]` where `j = i + 1` allows us to get the value we desire without evaluating the QuerySet (which is indispensable in a Subquery).